# Is Python multiprocessing timeout realtime or computation time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a programm, which creates up to 300 processes at once and tells them to do something computationaly intensive. I did not write this code, but these processes create another internal process, which has a time limit by just using `p.join(timeout=time_out)`. If the internal process takes longer than that, if will be terminated, right? Anyway sthat is not the question. I think my other process suffocate each other.

My question is: Is this timeout measured in realtime, or computational time? (just start time and end time measured, or does it only measure time, when the process is running?)

(Is `Pool()` a good alternative to fix this?)

Comment: 300 processes doing something computationaly intensive is a bad idea, unless you have 300 cores on your system and a huge memory... A time out is always given in real time, independently of how long the process was in waiting or suspended state so is a process is given a 10 seconds timeout and is it spends 5 seconds waiting for availability of resources (say because of a mutex) and spends 3 seconds in suspended state because no core is available, it will only run for 2 effective seconds.

Comment: A limited sized pool is always better than an unlimited number of processes, is this is the question.

Comment: Yes, taht is why i am asking, i know it is a bad idea. So pool is a good idea right? Colud you maybe add a answer on how to do this, because i dont get it ... :pensive: sry

Comment: I am sorry, but without more context for your real problem, I am not able to give better examples that what you can find on official Python [doc.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). My best advice is: read that doc, try to use is, and then ask a more precise question if you are stuck.